# shell function can't be called in node

Tags: node.js, shell

I have these:

An shell executable file:

```
function print() {
    echo 1
}
```

The package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "tests",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./shell.sh"
  }
}
```

When I ran `npm test` on a linux machine, I got this error

```
> tests@ test /home/xxxx/test
> ./shell.sh

./shell.sh: 1: ./shell.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Why so? Anybody has some insight? I am totally puzzled.

Comment: I didn't see a shebang in the script.  Is one there but not posted?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Node or npm, but with the shell script missing the [*shebang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Try instead e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Note the new line above

function print() {
    echo 1
}
```

Comment: with this line `#!/bin/sh` or not, it shows the same error. :( This error only occurs in a linux machine, not on my mac.

Comment: i.e. on mac, with or without shebang, it works. but on linux, with or without, it does not work.

Comment: @QiangLi Please try to drop the `function` keyword, not all shells support it.

Comment: that's a great finding. Why so though? My not-working shell is `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: could you help look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481734/shell-error-with-bash-bad-substitution-no-closing` too given your extensive experience with shell? That was a puzzling question to me too. thanks a lot!