# shell error with "-bash: bad substitution: no closing `)'"

Tags: macos, bash

I have this script (just copy and paste it into shell)

```
perl -c <(cat <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/perl
while( @mylist>1){
if($i > $initnum) {$i--;}
   {splice( @mylist,1);}
}
EOF
)
```

On one linux machine, I got `/dev/fd/63 syntax OK` output, which is ok. But on macbook terminal, I saw this

```
$ perl -c <(cat <<'EOF'
> #!/usr/bin/perl
> while( @mylist>1){
> if($i > $initnum) {$i--;}
>    {splice( @mylist,1);}
> }
> EOF
> )
-bash: bad substitution: no closing `)' in <(cat <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/perl
while( @mylist>1){
if($i > $initnum) {$i--;}
   splice( @mylist
}
EOF
)
```

My question is why such error. And ideally how to fix it on mac.

Comment: `bash --version` on each machine, please.

Comment: Appears to be a parser bug; the error occurs in version 3.2, but not in 4.3.

Comment: On mac version is `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`, on linux is `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @chepner is this a known bug?

Comment: I'd assume so, unless some other change in the parser in bash 4 fixed it by coincidence. If what you're really asking is, "Will it be fixed in 3.2?", I'd say the answer is "no". The 3.x branch will get security patches for serious bugs (like the Shellshock vulnerability), but it's unlikely to get bug fixes.

Comment: @chepner Based on this [SE post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137506/50240), I don't think this is a bug to 3.2 as it's reported in 4.2 as well.

Comment: Ah, I didn't check to see when the bug was fixed. In any case, it's almost certain that 3.2 is stuck with it, unless you can find a way to exploit it to run arbitrary code :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a parser bug in `bash` 3.2, but your example is a quite torturous replacement for a simple here document:

```
perl -c <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/perl
while( @mylist>1){
if($i > $initnum) {$i--;}
   {splice( @mylist,1);}
}
EOF
```

It does not seem likely that Apple will ever ship a newer version of `bash` by default, so your best bet is to install one yourself (via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), for example).

Comment: I know. I had other uses for that specific format. :)

Answer (score 2):

Likely an incompatible version (or broken version as @chepner commented) of bash on your MacOS, so you can naively rewrite it with `echo`:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/perl
while( @mylist>1){
if($i > $initnum) {$i--;}
    {splice( @mylist,1);}
}
' | perl -c
```

Or if you need to keep the `cat` business, you can bust it up into a [pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7046926/2908724):

```
cat <<'EOF' | perl -c
#!/usr/bin/perl
while( @mylist>1){
if($i > $initnum) {$i--;}
   {splice( @mylist,1);}
}
EOF
```